# Lotus Notes 8.5: Find mails that are not in any folder

Tags: email, lotus-notes

Tackling warnings that my inbox is about to exceed its quota, I discovered that there are several mails in my database that do not belong to any folder. I can see them via Views->All documents in the folder structure to the left.

All of them should have been deleted. How can I find them or delete them directly?

I am using Lotus Notes 8.5.